# Rest API Ajax Call Add parameter to URL

Tags: ajax, rest

Mostly, rest api url' s like:

```
/api/student:id/notes
```

I create a rest api and my urls like above. But I dont know how to add parameter before notes.

```
$.ajax({
    url : "api/v1/student/notes",
    data : { "id" : uid },
    type : "get",
    headers : { "Authorization" : api_key },
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

When I call like this, the url seems `/api/student/notes?id=5`. How can Iadd id parameter between student and notes?

Example url: http://www.sitepoint.com/best-practices-rest-api-scratch-introduction/

Comment: `url: 'api/v1/students/' + uid + '/notes'`

Comment: thanks @Phil, it works, please write as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, jQuery does not offer a neat API for injecting resource URI fragments like Angular's `$resource`. You'll have to build the URL yourself. Something like

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/v1/students/' + encodeURIComponent(uid) + '/notes',
    // and so on, no "data" required.
```